# Cocos2d-x CCRotateTo & Anchor Point

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-physics

So, I am using the CCRotateTo action to rotate an object, I have set the anchorPoint (-1,-1).

Q: When I click on that object it performs some task. By checking the location of the obj. but now the object (visible on the screen) is rotating around the original position. So, clicking on the object on the screen does nothing (because the object is not actually there, it is at the center of the circle) How do I cater this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

Happy Coding!

Comment: I am stuck here. Need.Help.

Comment: can you rephrase your question? its quite confusing. Exactly what does the object do on button click?